# Call Function From Code Behind In External JS without using ScriptManager or Ajax

Tags: javascript

I have this function from code behind (.aspx.cs):

```
public string GetData()
{
    string str = string.Format(@"SELECT * FROM DEPT.CATERGORY WHERE CAT in ('{0}') ", HfSearch.Value);
    DataTable dt = new DB().DBCat(str);
    return dt == null ? "[]" : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
}
```

On .aspx page, I retrive the json like this in the inline script:

```
rowData: <%= GetData() %>,
```

I have move the inline script to an external js file, but this above rowData: <%= GetData() %> is no longer working.  How should I code it in the external file?

Tia!

Answer (score 0):

I found this link that that helped me with the answer to my question. Hope this saves others too for days of searching.

[Using variables from server side code behind in functions in external JavaScript files](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7726f804-c858-4a90-a715-7ce7d767a313/using-variables-from-server-side-code-behind-in-functions-in-external-javascript-files?forum=asphtmlcssjavascript)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).